# Bullet Points (&bull;) as Password Input Placeholder

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, utf-8, slim-lang

I'm trying to get an **input field** to have a **placeholder with bullet points** in it.

```
= f.label "Password"
= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", 
    placeholder: "eg. &bull;"
```

This gives me the following html output:

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="user_Password">Password</label>
  <input value="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="eg. &bull;" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password">
</div>
```

The input placeholder is actually displaying `&bull;` where I want it to show a bullet.

Any ideas on how I can get the placeholder to display the bullet instead?

I tried to reproduce the error on CodePen; however, it is working there: [CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/Hendrie91/pen/xboPoZ)

I've also tried using another version of the encoding: `&#8226;` which produced the same output.

Note - I'm using Rails 4.2.0 with the [Slim template language](http://slim-lang.com/).

Comment: Solved (at least temporarily) by just copy/pasting some bullet points into the placeholder string `••••••••••••` if someone has another idea I'll accept it as an answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `raw`:

```
= f.label "Password"
= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", 
    placeholder: raw("&bull;")
```